# Supporting printer in a iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can we support printer in a iPhone application? I want to print a page from my application. Do I need to code for this in my app or this is a default operation supported by IOS. I am using IOS 4.3 & above.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something by not knowing IOS, but this sounds like it's on-topic. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156).

iOS can only print to "AirPrint" printers of which there aren't many. There are some apps that run on OS X that will "AirPrint enable" any attached printer. I use Printopia (no affiliation  other than as a happy user). There are some free ones but I haven't had as much success with them.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to google your question first :)

Everything you need to know:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html